# How to have a date "folder" in an MVC Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to change the site I'm working on so that when someone creates an article, the path would be "Articles/ViewArticle/2016-10-04/test" instead right now it's just "Articles/ViewArticle/test". When I implemented it, I got an instant 404.

I tried creating this route before & after the Default Route, but still no go:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ArticlesDefault",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{date}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Articles", action = "ViewArticle", date = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I should note that the "id" is actually stored in the database as [date]/ArticleTitle.

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Did you add the parameter in your view. `public ActionResult ViewArticle(string id, string date)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute routing instead. By using attribute routing you can construct the routes using the values of parameters passed to action methods.

More information on attribute routing is here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

if you do not want to use attribute routing, you can use `constraints` parameter of `MapRoute` method

**Edit:**

You can try any one of following approach

1. Without using attribute routing. I assume that your Id is in the form of `{date}/articleTitle`

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
   name: "ArticlesDefault",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Articles", action = "ViewArticle" },
   constraints: new { id = “\\d+” });
   ```
2. Using attribute routing. Best approach will be to separate article date and article title into two distinct parameters. Then you can use the following code.

   ```
   [Route("Articles/ViewArticle/{articleDate:datetime}/{articleTitle}")]
   public ActionResult ViewArticle(string articleTitle, DateTime articleDate)
   {
     //your action code goes here
   }
   ```

Comment: I tried to implement this by turning on attribute routing. First I had [Route("ViewArticle/{id})] but that didn't work (as the id is, for example, 2016-10-01/the-article-title). Tried something a little more complex like: [Route("ViewArticle/{regex(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\/[a-zA-Z-]+$}")] and MVC barked at me saying I couldn't have { or }. Any ideas?

Comment: Also tried this but got a 404:
routes.MapRoute(
    "ArticlesDefault",
    "ViewArticle/{id}",
    new { controller = "Articles", action = "ViewArticle" },
    new { id = @"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\/[a-zA-Z-]+$" },
    new[] { "oandp_redesign_web.Controllers" }
    );

Comment: @ajtatum Added code examples. Let me know if it is of any help

Comment: Went with your first suggestion, as when I turned on AttributeRouting the app threw some errors. Will definitely look into attribute routing, as it will be more useful in the future. But got it to work for now! Thank you!

Comment: I got AttributeRouting working. Before it was complaining about a dll, and I just had to remove it from the bin folder.